# Is it meaningful: “a building stays on its feet”?

Tags: meaning

Is this sentence correct:

> build a house to stay on its feet over the thousands of years.

Answer (score 12):

It's not 100% idiomatic in English to say that a house has "feet".  Instead we would say that a house (or any building) "will *stand*" for some length of time.

> That cottage has stood on that hillside for the past six hundred years.

> Over the past thousand years various churches have stood in the middle of town.

> They built so well, that office building should stand for the next century, at least.

As J.R. points out in his comment below, it's fine to use the expression as anyone would know what you mean.  It's just not something I've ever heard or read.

Comment: I agree with this answer (and even upvoted it), but it should be noted that unidiomatic is not necessarily "wrong." One blogger recently said in a column: [_No house will stand **on its feet** if it isn’t repaired regularly_](http://washingtonvacationrentalsinfo.com/2016/saving-money-on-your-house/).

Comment: @j.r. Certainly true that "not idiomatic" is not the same as "wrong". But "not idiomatic" is usually the same as "should have a good reason for saying it in this unusual way". :-) If you're trying to be poetic, or make a specific point, cool.

Comment: Agree with @Jay (+1 for both of you). This is all essentially a very periphrastic way of saying that it's, well, wrong. Call a spade a spade.

Comment: On the other hand, a house can have footings.

Comment: @keshlam and square *footage*.

Answer (score 4):

An idiomatic equivalent for "stay on its feet" would be "build a house to **remain standing** (or **continue to stand**) over the thousands of years" or "over the millennia".

If you really want to include the concept of "feet" somehow, you could say "build a house **to stand on its foundations** ..."

Note "foundations" meaning "the lowest part load-bearing part of a building structure" is usually plural in BrE, though it can be singular. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/foundation.